# What is the mysterious secret whitespace character?

Tags: c#, regex, string, expression

I've got an issue with regex. I've got code right now that replaces tabs `(\t)`, newlines `(\n)`, and any alphabetic or numeric character followed by a carriage return `(([a-z,A-Z,0-9])\r)` with blanks. They work great! Problem is, it's missing a specific newline character that I can't see, even with the symbols visible in Notepad++. 
For example, a line in this file ends as such:

`.../exploits/36776`

The line below it should be appended to the line, but there is no indication of any standard newline or return characters. Please advise.

Comment: It's not *too long* for `Notepad++` to display on one line, is it?

Comment: Is the missing char `\n`?

Comment: Could you please provide the exact input and exact expected output? In case you cannot copy/paste some symbols, [convert them to hex here](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/).

Comment: @xanatos: You are welcome. Unfortunately, the question is not updated, I think it will remain a mystery :-(

Comment: @stribizhev sorry I didn't get back to this in time, but the issue was fixed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few [white space characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) defined in Unicode.

You can try and match by unicode category, e.g. with

```
\p{Zs}
```

to match the *white space* category.  [More information](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).